# Call python script from mysql trigger

Tags: python, mysql

I read http://crazytechthoughts.blogspot.sg/2011/12/call-external-program-from-mysql.html and install [lib_mysqludf_sys](https://github.com/mysqludf/lib_mysqludf_sys#readme)

And try to call python script inside mysql trigger.

Here is my test trigger:

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS ljj_rigger;

CREATE TRIGGER ljj_rigger 
AFTER INSERT ON test_trigger 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
        DECLARE cmd1 CHAR(255);
        DECLARE cmd2 CHAR(255);
        DECLARE cmd3 CHAR(255);
        DECLARE result1 int(10);
        DECLARE result2 int(10);
        DECLARE result3 int(10);
        SET cmd1 = 'python /home/jaskey1103/python/test.py';
        SET cmd2 = 'touch /home/jaskey1103/python/bybash';
        SET cmd3 = '/home/jaskey1103/python/callpy.sh';

        SET result1 = sys_exec(cmd1);
        SET result2 = sys_exec(cmd2);
        SET result3 = sys_exec(cmd3);

        insert into test_trigger_copy(value) values(result1);
        insert into test_trigger_copy(value) values(result2);
        insert into test_trigger_copy(value) values(result3);
END;


commit;
```

But when the trigger runs, I could find new file `bytouch` but can't find new file created by python script.

And for testing, the inserted result into copy table are: 0,0,512.

test.py:

```
import os

def touch(fname, times=None):
    fhandle = open(fname, 'a')
    try:
        os.utime(fname, times)
    finally:
        fhandle.close()

print 'creating file'
touch("bypython")
```

callpy.sh:

```
python test.py
```

Comment: Just a guess: maybe the file ended up in a different location as you only specified a filename and no path (and it would end up in whatever directory the process uses as default), try using a full path for the filename like so: `SET cmd1 = 'python /home/jaskey1103/python/test.py > /home/jaskey1103/python/log';`

Comment: @jpw even I remove `> /home/jaskey1103/python/log` will not work since I could not find file 'bypython'.

Comment: If I understand the code right the `bypython` file should end up in the home directory of the user account which is used to run MySQL. Perhaps that user can't read the python file in your home directory? You could look at the return value from `sys_exec` to see if you got any error.

Comment: Did you heck the permission of test.py or a folder where test.py will write? 
What value return by `result1` varialble? may be I will shows the error.

Comment: @jpw  what kind of method could I check that ？ insert a record into one table ？  can have an sample ？

Comment: @ji-ruh I maked it 777 already

Comment: ok, what is result of variable `result1`? 
For now just insert the value of result1 into your table, and post it here

Comment: @ji-ruh , weird,  both of the results are 0, though call directly by "touch" created the file